# Why does the neo4j-shell index query work and cypher return 0 rows

Tags: neo4j

I have an index called plants.  I've indexed a bunch of nodes using name: `index -i plants name`

When I use the shell index command to query I can get rows back using *.  When I use Cypher the wild card doesn't work.  However an exact match does.  Why doesn't the wildcard work in Cypher?  Is my syntax wrong?

```
neo4j-sh (foo,0)$ start n=node:plants(name="*")
> return n;
+---+
| n |
+---+
+---+
0 row
0 ms

neo4j-sh (foo,0)$ index -q plants name "*"
(me)
(Broccoli,23)
(Basil,24)
(Kale,22)
(Brussel_sprouts,30)
(Sunflowers,27)
(Cilantro,26)
(Parsley,28)
(Beets,25)
(Corn,1)
(Cauliflower,17)
(Lettuce,18)
(Pumpkin,15)
(Garlic,16)
(Tomato,13)
(Beans,14)
(Peas,19)
(Potatoes,20)
(Favas,21)
(Cabbage,12)
(Cucumber,11)
(Onions,5)
(Carrots,3)

neo4j-sh (foo,0)$ start n=node:plants(name="Corn")

> return n;
+----------------------------------+
| n                                |
+----------------------------------+
| Node[1]{name:"Corn",height:"84"} |
+----------------------------------+
1 row
2 ms

neo4j-sh (foo,0)$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the Lucene syntax for that kind of query. Like so:

```
start n=node:plants("name:*")
...
```

Comment: excellent, that works!  I wonder why you would ever use the (name="Corn") syntax when ("name:Corn") works just fine?  As does ("name:C???")...

Comment: Yeah, I still do use `=` syntax with parameters. ex. `(name={name})`. I find it easier to look at that way.

Comment: Because the direct lookup should be faster, and you can use a parameter for the actual value you look for. Not for the whole lucene query.